# How to change the password in codeigniter and validate the field using jquery

Tags: php, codeigniter

my view page is `password.php`:

```
<form>
    oldpassword<input type="password" name="oldpassword" id="oldpassword"/><br>

    newpassword<input type="password" name="newpassword" id="newpassword"/><br>

    confirmpassword<input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword"/><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="changepassword"/>
</form>
```

What code should be put in controller page.password must be `MD5`.

Comment: Have you tried anything or you are just waiting for someone to write the code for you?

Answer (score 0):

There is no jQuery used in my script, you can change the submit function via jQuery if you want.... I did it without jQuery

```
public function saveData(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules ( "oldpassword", "Old Password", "trim|required|xss_clean|callback_passwordCheck" );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules ( "newpassword", "New Password", "trim|required|matches[repassword]|xss_clean|min_length[5]" );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules ( "repassword", "Confirm Password", "trim|required|xss_clean" );
    if ($this->form_validation->run () == false) {
        $this->updatePassword ();
    }else{
        $md5pass = $this->input->post('newpassword');
        $data ['username'] = $this->session->userdata ( 'username' );
        $data ['password'] = md5($md5pass);

        $this->load->model('loginModel');
        $this->loginModel->updatePassword('username',$data ['username'],$data);

        //var_dump($data); 
    }
}

public function passwordCheck(){
    $username = $this->session->userdata ( 'username' );
    $md5pass = $this->input->post('oldpassword');
    $this->load->model('loginModel');
    $results = $this->loginModel->getOldPassword($username);
    $currentPass = $results->password;

    if($md5pass==$currentPass){
        return true;
    }else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('passwordCheck', 'Invalid current password, please try again');
        return false;
    }
}
```

`<?php echo form_open("loginController/savedata",'class="cmxform form-horizontal tasi-form" id="commentForm"')?>`

```
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Old Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <?=form_input($fldoldPassword) ?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">New Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <?=form_input($fldNewPassword) ?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <?=form_input($fldRePassword) ?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">&nbsp;</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Save</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">&nbsp;</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <?=validation_errors('<p class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in">'); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```